# Why my DMARC are not giving permission for reports?

Tags: email-server, centos6, dmarc, cpanel

In all servers I have a DMARC record for sernd email in ahother domain in my WHM , but when test with  mxtoolbox show this error : 'DMARC are not giving permission for your reports' this is the stucture of my recors:

***Note. The server is a CENTOS 6 with WHM and all domains has a CPanel***

> In the external domain sender (example1.com.mx) and 
>    the external domain (example@example.com) i have this:
>
> ```
> _dmarc 86400 in TXT "v=DMARC1;  sp=none;p=none; rua=mailto:example@example.com; ruf=mailto:example@example.com;"example1.com.mx._report._dmarc.mail 86400 IN TXT "v=DMARC1;"
> ```

This is correct?
Thanks

Comment: Where did you come up with `example1.com.mx._report._dmarc.mail`

Comment: In a website set this in a example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your report DNS record is not as documentation required.

On the receiver domain, you need `example1.com.mx._report._dmarc.example.com.`

https://dmarc.org/2015/08/receiving-dmarc-reports-outside-your-domain/

Comment: Ok, but this record is in **example1.com.mx** ,in **example.com** or 
both Thanks

Comment: Example.com is where this record for example.com goes.

Comment: And another cuestion, I will need wait wait 24 hours for see the changes or is automatic?

Comment: That depends on your dns ttl and slave replication method, typically I'd expect the change in under 2 hours.

Comment: if you have bind and bash you can run this little script to check your slaves...

`for NS in $(dig +short NS example.com); do dig @$NS TXT example1.com.mx._report._dmarc.example.com. +short; done`

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try to run , has a little problem to connect sometimes but I will try to run this script :D

Comment: Thanks ya can fix the problem in any server also I see another problem for this in my *DMARC1* add the param *adkim=r;* but this not was detected in a domain of server and this is for example: server:*server.example.com* and domain is example.com a mark this error yet